# Angular Material divs should wrap their content the same way

Tags: angularjs, responsive-design, material-design

I have an angular material page with several input fields. These are ordered in two virtuall "boxes". If the screen is big, the boxes should be displayed side by side and among each other on small screens.

```
Input 1         Input 4
Input 2         Input 5
Input 3
```

On bigger screens. And on smaller screens:

```
Input 1
Input 2
Input 3
Input 4
Input 5
```

I use a `<div layout="column">` around each "block" and around everything a `<div layout="row" layout-gt-xs="column">`.

My problem is, that the second block is as high as the first block on bigger screens and the input fields are not in the same lines, which doesn't look good. It looks more like this:

```
Input 1         Input 4

Input 2
                Input 5
Input 3
```

What shall I do in order that Input 1 and 4 (2 and 5) appear on the same line (like in the first example)? If I use `<md-grid-list>` the item-order is messed up on small screens, so it is not really an option.

Here is a complete code example: http://plnkr.co/edit/HrkLYYEowL31zqD0Jqq2?p=preview

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about removing flex attributes for Input 4 and 5 ?

```
<div flex layout="column">

    <md-input-container >
        <label>Input 4</label>
        <input type="text" value="Mock-Text" />
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container >
        <label>Input 5</label>
        <input type="text" value="Mock-Text" />
    </md-input-container>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought, flex would only change the horizontal layout, but I was clearly wrong.